# How to compare row with previous row to detect changes?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `points`:

```
CREATE TABLE "points" (
    "match_id"    INTEGER,
    "player_id"   INTEGER,
    "opponent_id" INTEGER,
    "set"         INTEGER,
    "point"       INTEGER,
    "won"         INTEGER
);
```

Example data:

| match_id | player_id | opponent_id | set | point | won |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 8 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 9 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 13 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 14 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 16 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 18 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 19 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 8 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 9 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 11 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 12 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 13 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 14 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 15 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 2 | 16 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 6 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 7 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 8 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 9 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 11 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 12 | 0 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 13 | 1 |
| 37346937 | 14054027 | 16471936 | 3 | 14 | 0 |

To determine autocorrelation in `won` I want to compare for each point whether the same player also won the previous point. Each match has two players. If one player wins, the other one automatically loses. So, my query should be focused on only one player.

Second part of query :

```
SELECT cur.match_id, cur.set, cur.point, cur.won, prev.won
FROM points cur 
LEFT JOIN points prev 
ON (cur.match_id, cur.player_id, cur.set, cur.point) =
   (prev.match_id, prev_player_id, prev.set, prev.point + 1);
```

For following example of `won` the number of switches is 3:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I use `cur.won` and `prev.won` in combination with the single player condition to get the number of switches `n_switches` of each `match_id`?

Expected output:

| match_id | set | n_switches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37346937 | 1 | 12 |
| 37346937 | 2 | 4 |
| 37346937 | 3 | 8 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `LAG()` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(won, 1, won) OVER (PARTITION BY match_id, "set"
                                               ORDER BY point) <> won
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT match_id, "set", SUM(cnt) AS n_switches
FROM cte
GROUP BY match_id, "set"
ORDER BY match_id, "set";
```

The logic of the `CASE` expression is to assign 1 to any row whose previous record's `won` value differs from the current one, for a given match and set.  We then aggregate by match and set and sum those counts to get the final result.